# Visualizar imagenes desde mysql en xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

Tengo una base de datos con con la tabla categoria en el cual tiene la columna imagen con el URL de cada imagen, como puedo hacer que se vean en el UIImage.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import WebKit

class HomeViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    var values:NSArray = []

    var arr =  ["http://totalplanning.guiaparatuseventos.com/imagenes/subcategorias/cita-romantica%20(1).png","http://totalplanning.guiaparatuseventos.com/imagenes/salon.png","http://totalplanning.guiaparatuseventos.com/imagenes/curriculum-de-mujer.png","http://totalplanning.guiaparatuseventos.com/imagenes/belleza.png","http://totalplanning.guiaparatuseventos.com/imagenes/planeacion.png","http://totalplanning.guiaparatuseventos.com/imagenes/camara.png","http://totalplanning.guiaparatuseventos.com/imagenes/musica.png","http://totalplanning.guiaparatuseventos.com/imagenes/mobiliario.png","http://totalplanning.guiaparatuseventos.com/imagenes/familia.png"]

    //let colors = [UIColor.brownColor(),UIColor.purpleColor(), UIColor.yellowColor(), UIColor.greenColor(), UIColor.blueColor(), UIColor.grayColor()]

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {

        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        let proxyViewForStatusBar : UIView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0,self.view.frame.size.width, 20))
        proxyViewForStatusBar.backgroundColor = hexStringToUIColor("#1C1C1C")
        self.view.addSubview(proxyViewForStatusBar)

        get();

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func hexStringToUIColor (hex:String) -> UIColor {
        var cString:String = hex.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet() as NSCharacterSet).uppercaseString

        if (cString.hasPrefix("#")) {
            cString = cString.substringFromIndex(cString.startIndex.advancedBy(1))
        }

        if ((cString.characters.count) != 6) {
            return UIColor.grayColor()
        }

        var rgbValue:UInt32 = 0
        NSScanner(string: cString).scanHexInt(&rgbValue)

        return UIColor(
            red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,
            green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,
            blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,
            alpha: CGFloat(1.0)
        )
    }


    func get(){
        let url = NSURL(string:"PHP")
        let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)

        values = ((try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments)) as? NSArray)!

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return values.count

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SpecialCell

        let maindata = values[indexPath.row]

        cell.nombre.text = maindata["nombre"] as? String
        cell.descripcion.text = maindata["descripcion"] as? String

        let url = arr [indexPath.row]
        let urls = NSURL(string: url)
        let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: urls!)
        let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
        let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
            (data,response,error) -> Void in
            if ( error == nil && data != nil ) {
                func display_image() {
                    cell.imagen.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                }

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), display_image)
            }
        }
        task.resume()

        let colors = [hexStringToUIColor("#FF0000"),hexStringToUIColor("#FF8000"),hexStringToUIColor("#FFFF00"),hexStringToUIColor("#80FF00"),hexStringToUIColor("00FFFF"),hexStringToUIColor("#0080FF"),hexStringToUIColor("#A901DB"),hexStringToUIColor("#FF00FF"),hexStringToUIColor("#FF0080")]

        cell.accessoryType = .DisclosureIndicator
        cell.imagen.backgroundColor = colors[indexPath.row % colors.count]

        return cell

    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
        if (segue.identifier == "show") {

            if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
            {
                if let vc: ViewController = segue.destinationViewController as? ViewController {
                    vc.idCategoria = values[indexPath.item]["idCategoria"] as! String

                    print(vc.idCategoria)

                }

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeramente necesitas una forma de obtener la información de la base de datos a tu app, para esto se necesita un servicio web, se recomienda que sea de tipo REST para que la comunicación sea más transparente y ahorres ancho de banda del dispositivo. Para hacer la llamda al servidor la puedes realizar de la siguiente manera:

```
//Variables globales
let apiUrl: String = "http://midominio.com/MiWebService"
var urlString: String = ""
var lstImagenes: [String] = []

    //Llamada al servidor
    let url = NSURL(string: apiUrl)!
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    session.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { (data:NSData?, response: NSURLResponse?,error: NSError?) -> Void in

        //Leer el JSON
        do{
            if let _ = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding){

                //Parsear el JSON
                let jsonDictionary = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary

                //Obtenemos la cantidad de imagenes
                let cantidadImagenes = jsonDictionary["count"] as! Int
                let imagenes = jsonDictionary["imagenes"] as! NSArray

                //Recorremos el arreglo de imagenes
                for(var i: Int = 0; i < cantidadImagenes; i++){
                    self.lstImagenes.append(imagenes[i] as! String)
                }

            }

        } catch{
            print("Ocurrio un error")
        }
    }).resume()
```

Después de que obtenemos la información del web service ahora utilizamos una libreria llamada AlamofireImage y Alamofire, estas nos van a ayudar con el manejo de la red y de la memoria del telefono ya que se encargan de hacer las llamadas asincronas y a que nuestra aplicación no se trabe al estar trabajando con imagenes desde URL y almacene el cache de las mismas. Para mostrar las imagenes lo hacemos de la siguiente forma, primero hay que importar las librerias en nuestra clase. Para esto hay que agregar las referencias a nuestro proyecto eso lo podemos hacer desde cocoapods o alguna forma de las que ellos nos indican en su página de GitHub.

Alamofire: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

AlamofireImage: https://github.com/Alamofire/AlamofireImage

```
import Alamofire
import AlamofireImage
```

Por ultimo mandamos a llamar el metodo `af_setImageWithURL` de AlamofireImage de la siguiente manera asignandole el UIImageView donde la queremos mostrar.

```
        //El arreglo lstImagenes contiene las URL's de las imagenes ejemplo: http://www.midominio.com/Imagenes/imagen01.jpg
        let urlImagen = NSURL(string: lstImagenes[indiceImagen])
        //imgImagen es mi UIImageView
        self.imgImagen.af_setImageWithURL(urlImagen!)
```

Este código esta probado con Swift 2.2 y IOS 9.3

ACTUALIZACIÓN:

Metodo para la carga de imagenes:

```
//Carga las imagenes de forma asincrona
    func asyncImage(urlString: String, completionHandler:(image: UIImage?, url: String) -> ()) {

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), {()in

            if let url = NSURL(string: urlString), let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url), let image = UIImage(data: data) {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {() in
                    completionHandler(image: image, url: urlString)
                })

            } else {

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {() in
                    completionHandler(image: nil, url: urlString)
                })

            }

        })

    }
```

Uso del metodo:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{



    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SpecialCell

    let maindata = values[indexPath.row]

    cell.nombre.text = maindata["nombre"] as? String
    cell.descripcion.text = maindata["descripcion"] as? String

    let url = arr [indexPath.row]
    let urls = NSURL(string: url)
    let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: urls!)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    //Uso del metodo asincrono
    asyncImage(urlString) { (image, url) -> () in
      cell.imagen.image = image
    }




   let colors = [hexStringToUIColor("#FF0000"),hexStringToUIColor("#FF8000"),hexStringToUIColor("#FFFF00"),hexStringToUIColor("#80FF00"),hexStringToUIColor("00FFFF"),hexStringToUIColor("#0080FF"),hexStringToUIColor("#A901DB"),hexStringToUIColor("#FF00FF"),hexStringToUIColor("#FF0080")]

    cell.accessoryType = .DisclosureIndicator
    cell.imagen.backgroundColor = colors[indexPath.row % colors.count]



    return cell



}
```

Comment: Bueno el webservice y todo ya lo tengo, obtengo los datos y los muestro en una table view lo unico que me falta son las imagenes pero no quiero utilizar una libreria por problemas con la que pidia su aplicación

te anexo mi codigo para que veas como anda:

pd: Soy nuevo en esto y es para liberar mis practicas por si esta muy feo el codigo.

Comment: Puedes probar con el metodo que agregue en mi respuesta, este metodo utiliza unicamente las librerias propias de Swift.

Comment: ¿Pero no las jalas del webservice o si? el arreglo que cree con los url si me funciona y muestra las imagenes pero quiero que las agarre de la base de datos para deshacerme de ese arreglo

Comment: El arreglo que tienes con las imagenes predefinidas lo tienes que poblar cuando haces la llamada al tu web service, por ejemplo, puedes tener un webservice "http://midominio.com/ObtenerImagenes" y que este te regrese un JSON con la información de las imagenes por ejemplo {"imagenes":["http://midominio.com/Imagenes/imagen1.jpg","http://midominio.com/Imagenes/imagen2.jpg","http://midominio.com/Imagenes/imagen3.jpg"]} esto es un JSON Array y lo iteras a traves de un for tal cual como esta en la primer sección de mi respuesta

Comment: Oh ya, ya
ya entendi, gracias lo probare y te digo

Comment: Perfecto, espero que te funcione!

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciono :D